# C++20 Concepts Apply constraint on templated function

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'd like to start with c++20 concepts.

```
class MyClass
{
  template<typename T>
  void copy(const T& data);
};
```

`copy()` only works if `T` is `is_trivially_copyable`. Before C++20 I'd have used

```
static_assert(is_trivially_copyable<T>, "Type must be trivially copyable");
```

within the `copy` function.

But from my understanding, this is an issue where concepts can be used.
After some googling I came up with

```
template <typename T>
concept isTriviallyCopyable = std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>;
```

however when adding this to the function

```
class MyClass
{
  template<isTriviallyCopyable>
  void copy(const isTriviallyCopyable & data);
};
```

This gives me a compiler error. Could you help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a type parameter for your `sTriviallyCopyable` to be applied to.  That would give you

```
class MyClass
{
    template<isTriviallyCopyable T>
    void copy(const T & data);
};
```